# How to live stream mp3 frames by frames in naudio

Tags: c#, naudio, live-streaming

I am trying to live stream the audio in mp3 format while recording but i cannot achieve good streaming quality.

what i am doing is getting 10 seconds of PCM data from "WI_DataAvailable" and convert it to MP3 then send the frames in network. it produce little silent between the 10 sec of data.

I like to stream continues mp3 frames by frames while recording. is there any proper way?

Comment: Are you encoding each 10 seconds of mp3 individually? If so, you'll never be able to butt them "end-to-end" without gaps because of the limitations of mp3 (mp3 cannot be arbitrary length, and must be a multiples of the frame size, usually 1152 samples). You also need to consider that there is a "ramp-up" time for the encoder, which means that you'll get audible artifacts at your boundaries. You'll need to continuously encode the audio rather than starting a new encoding session for each 10 second interval.

Comment: yes i am encoding each 10 seconds individually. but how to encode and get the frames simultaneously to send the frame into network? By using LameMP3FileWriter i can only able to write the stream. is there any alternate way for that?

Comment: I wrote an mp3 streamer once, but on an old computer (which I virtualized). I'll take a look to see if it's there...

Comment: Assuming that you're using [this LameMP3FileWriter](https://github.com/Corey-M/NAudio.Lame/blob/master/MP3FileWriter.cs), the constructor takes a Stream. Why not supply a network stream instead of a file stream? How are you streaming? Over HTTP? What's your setup?

Comment: I am streaming frame over UDP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that LameMP3FileWriter takes a Stream to write to, I would suggest implementing your own stream class and simply writing all the data that arrives in the `Write` method to UDP. Then you can pass this to the LameMP3FileWriter.

Here's a bare-bones stream class that should get you started. You'll need to fill in the blanks for method `Write`, and possibly `Flush`. I imagine you can leave everything else as NotImplemented.

```
public class UdpStream:Stream
{
    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        //you'll definitely need to implement this...
        //write the buffer to UDP
    }

    public override void Flush()
    {
        //you might need to implement this
    }

    public override bool CanRead
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanSeek
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void SetLength(long value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }


    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override long Length
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public override long Position { 
        get{throw new NotImplementedException();} 
        set{throw new NotImplementedException();} 
    }
}
```

Comment: I have little confusion on flush What actually is doing in stream

Comment: @Aran: You can probably get away with doing nothing in Flush seeing as you probably won't need to buffer anything... just write everything out to UDP in the Write method and you should be good to go. I'd love to hear how this works out for you.

Comment: @Aran: Of course, if the LameMP3FileWriter actually messes with the `Position` property, you'll be back to the drawing board. I didn't check.

Comment: ya Sure thing i'll implement and test it.

Comment: @Aran: I just checked now... it Writes and Flushes, so just sort out the Write method, leave the Flush implementation doing nothing and it ***should*** work.